# How do I get local timestamp for 12:00AM in given timezone

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a time string specified as "12:00" or "12:00AM". I want to get the timestamp that corresponds to say new york of that time for **today**, where naturally today changes from day to day. So my method would be something like

```
new DateTime("12:00AM", DateTimeZone.forID(timezone));
```

But I am getting an

```
IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "12:00AM"
```

I am using Joda time. Does anyone know how to do this right? I need responses in java.

Comment: `Explaination myExplaination = new Explaination("joda DateTime does not seem to have a constructor that takes a String.");`

Answer (score 0):

Joda takes time on a 24 hour clock. Also preface your time with a capital T like this:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime("T00:00", DateTimeZone.forID("US/Eastern"));
```

The example they give in the user guide looks like this:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime("2004-12-13T21:39:45.618-08:00");
```

There are lots more examples in the user guide: [Link](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html)

Comment: so would 12:00 be noon? so that I need to write 00 for 12:00am?

Comment: @user3093402 Correct, no need for am or pm using 24 hour clock.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the documentation for [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html)?

You could use this constructor:

```
//DateTime(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth, int hourOfDay, int minuteOfHour, DateTimeZone zone)
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014,2,1,12,00,"UTC-07:00");
```

Comment: The only thing I may enter by hand is the time portion, not the entire date. Today must be assumed.

Answer (score 0):

Here a link which provides an exact answer to why your code fails.

The javadoc about [DateTime-constructor with Object and DateTimeZone](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28java.lang.Object,%20org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29) declares:
"The String formats are described by ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()." which [links](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeParser%28%29) to:

```
 datetime          = time | date-opt-time
 time              = 'T' time-element [offset]
 date-opt-time     = date-element ['T' [time-element] [offset]]
 date-element      = std-date-element | ord-date-element | week-date-element
 std-date-element  = yyyy ['-' MM ['-' dd]]
 ord-date-element  = yyyy ['-' DDD]
 week-date-element = xxxx '-W' ww ['-' e]
 time-element      = HH [minute-element] | [fraction]
 minute-element    = ':' mm [second-element] | [fraction]
 second-element    = ':' ss [fraction]
 fraction          = ('.' | ',') digit+
 offset            = 'Z' | (('+' | '-') HH [':' mm [':' ss [('.' | ',') SSS]]])
```

As everybody can clearly see there is no AM/PM-marker in those supported string formats for constructor. Instead only ISO-8601-formats are expected. I am not sure how you have to interprete strings like "12:00" if also strings like "12:00AM" are expected as input. But it is common practice and so also done by Joda Time to interprete "12:00AM" as "T00:00" in ISO-style, that is midnight at the begin of a day. So you might first do some preprocessing if you expect different input formats. Otherwise you should seriously consider the [format-engine](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) of Joda Time:

```
DateTime dt = 
  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mma")
                .withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(timezone))
                .parseDateTime("12:00AM");
```